# How do I pass an array to fields_for in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, field, nested-forms, formbuilder

I want to use `fields_for` on a subset of records in an association.

I have a `Month` model, which `has_many :payments`.

But in my form in my view I only want to have `fields_for` some of those payments. For example:

```
- fields_for @month.payments.large
```

This doesn't work.

Can I pass a set of records to `fields_for`, rather than the usual symbol (`fields_for :payments`) approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add additional association for large payments, for example:

```
class Month < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :payments
  has_many :large_payments, :class_name => "Payment", :conditions => "value > 1000000"
end
```

After that you can use `fields_for` in common way:

```
- fields_for :large_payments
```

I think to encapsulate this logic on a model side is a better approach then in the view.

Comment: Good thinking - that did the trick. I also had to add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :large_payments`. Thanks :)

Comment: You are right. And you should add `attr_accessible :large_payments_attributes`, if you protect your payment model from mass-assignment (good practice to protect).

Answer (score 5):

You can, however, use an array of objects without having to create any additional associations. For example, let's say that in your controller you prepared some array of @large_payments, then in the view you can do the following:

```
<%= f.fields_for :payments, @large_payments do |payment| %> ...
```

That way if you've got a pretty big form or multiple pages of forms, and you don't want to have to create an additional association for each group that you want to display, you don't have to.

Comment: I could be doing something wrong, but I cannot get this solution to work.