# Rails 6 nested not displaying form_with

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-for, nested-form-for, form-with

```rb
class CustomerType < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :workspace, inverse_of: :customer_type
  validates_presence_of :workspace
end

class Workspace < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  has_one :customer_type
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :customer_type, allow_destroy: true
end
# controller

  def new
    @workspace = Workspace.new
    @workspace.build_customer_type
  end
# _form
<%= form_with(model: [:back_office, @workspace]) do |form| %>
...
  <%= form.fields_for :customer_type, @workspace.customer_type do |s| %>
    <%= s.label :build, 'Build', class: 'form-check-label'%>
    <%= s.radio_button :build, 'build', class: 'form-check-input'%>
  <% end %>
...
<% end %>


class CreateCustomerTypes < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :customer_types, id: :uuid do |t|
      t.boolean :build, default: false
      t.boolean :grow, default: false
      t.boolean :connector, default: false
      t.references :workspace, null: false, foreign_key: true, type: :uuid

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

The creation between `workspace` and `customerType` is done well my puts in the controller shows me the class

I know there is probably a post with the solution but I couldn't find it

it does not appear in the form is there an error?

Comment: you might have to call  `@workspace.custom_type.build` in your new action after `Workspace.new`

Comment: it does exactly the same thing, nothing on the display.
I think it should be added in the form_with but I don't have the syntax

Comment: try something along this way: `= f.fields_for :answers, @survey.answers do |answer_form|` with the build in place

Comment: <% form.fields_for :customer_type, @workspace.customer_type do |s| %>
doesn't work as weird.
Do I have to show you more code?

Comment: hm not sure right now, can you see any fields from form_with or are only the fields_for not shown?

Comment: only fields_for

Comment: Ok one last thing I noticed that in your presented code <% form.fields_for :customer_type do |s| %> is not indented, but it should be. not sure if it is just a mistake from copying.

Comment: I reassure you it is well indented it is just the copy, I deleted everything except what is shown above with the modification, nothing changes.
impossible to enter `fields_for` but <%= @workspace.customer_type %> before the tag works fine

Comment: have you allowed the customer_type_attributes in your params? you could try like shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47111988/nested-forms-using-form-with-and-fields-for-iteration-not-working

Comment: it doesn't work either, I must have made an error somewhere but it's impossible to get a result in the fields_for.
maybe my variable is named `build` ?

Comment: you can check if fields_for is shown at all if you just add a dummy p tag or something in there if it is an error with the s.label and s.radio_button

Comment: he doesn't want to enter the fileds_for at all
if I do with workspace  it works ```<%= fields_for :name, @workspace do |t| %>
    <p>test</p>
  <% end %>```

Comment: this line  `@workspace.build_customer_type` should be `@workspace.costumer_type.build`

Comment: undefined method `build` for nil:NilClass, I have a `build` variable in it

Comment: this seems strange, can you create the models with associations in rails console? If not there might be something wrong on the model level.

Comment: nothing works I removed the column nothing either,
a snake case problem ? very unlikely

Comment: the file should be named `costumer_type.rb` but I think _ should be fine as far as I know.

Comment: I think it comes from the migration maybe?
```customer_type => t.references :workspace, null: false, foreign_key: true, type: :uuid```
```workspace => id```, the file name is good

Comment: could be maybe have a look at the rails associations guides they have pretty good examples imo, I am not sure about the uuid havent used this so far

Comment: This is my mistake you were right about the indentation.

Comment: ah great, would you mind accepting my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your form was not indented correctly:

it should look like

```rb
# _form
<%= form_with(model: [:back_office, @workspace]) do |form| %>
...
  <%= form.fields_for :customer_type, @workspace.customer_type do |s| %>
    <%= s.label :build, 'Build', class: 'form-check-label'%>
    <%= s.radio_button :build, 'build', class: 'form-check-input'%>
  <% end %>
...
<% end %>
```